# The app's executable could not be signed again for submission to the App Store

Tags: macos, app-store-connect, code-signing, appstore-approval, mac-app-store

Trying to send mac app build via new iTunes Connect, after it has been successfully uploaded and validated and clicked to submit for review, it ends with following error:

"The app's executable could not be signed again for submission to the App Store. Make sure that you don't use prerelease or uncertified tools."

App is built with Xcode 5.1.1 and is normal obj-c mac app. Has any of you been able to resolve it?
(the message is from web app, it's not xcode codesign problem)

Comment: just got the same thing...did you figure it out?

Comment: Yes and no, in few days it resolved itself and i was able to send it to review.

Comment: Ah, the magic...I'm hoping the same will happen here; I ran all the codesign tests I could think of and all seems to be ok (tm) - now we wait....

Comment: Got this issue in 2022 because I was missing disk space, cleaning a bit my disk then trying again with the same .ipa worked for me